# MUI Component Error Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik-material-ui

I was spending too much time finding answers to this error.

Have been already added key `key={models.model_id}` on that map function.

On my form:

```
<JSelect
    label="Model"
    labelId="assembly_model_id"
    name="product_model_id"
    value={values.product_model_id}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    onChange={handleChange}
    errors={errors}
>
    {models.map((model) => {
        return (
            <MenuItem key={models.model_id} value={model.model_id}>
                {model.model_code}
            </MenuItem>
        );
    })}
</JSelect>
```

On my JSelect functional component:

```
const JSelect = ({ children, value, id, label, labelId, name, placeholder, type, onChange, onBlur, size, rows }) => {
    return (
        <FormControl fullWidth size={size ? size : 'small'}>
            <InputLabel id={labelId}>{label}</InputLabel>
            <Select labelId={labelId} id={id ? id : name} name={name} value={value} label={label} onBlur={onBlur} onChange={onChange}>
                {children}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    );
};
```

Error screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: could you reproduce the problem on codesandbox?

Comment: did you check your models.model_id is not empty or there is no duplicate on it? btw, to avoid this error you can use the second parameter of map function "index" instead of model.models_id

Comment: No it is not empty, the data is from the database it is unique. codesandbox live: https://codesandbox.io/live/17df4218655

Answer (score 1):

{models. Map((model,index) => {
return (

{model.model_code}

);
})}

add index next to model and assign this to key. check above code

Comment: <MenuItem key={index} value={model.model_id}> thanks, seems to be working but a new error show after selecting from the list. (A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component)